# Why my mouse wheel vertical scrolling step resets to "1"?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mouse, hardware

Every time I fire up Visual Studio, my vertical scroll settings for mouse (and the touch pad as well, in case a mouse is not attached at that moment) resets to "1" from "3". I set the scroll step to "3" and after coding a couple of lines, testing and debug, the scroll step size resets to "1" again.

Any ideas?

system info: Samsung notebook, Windows 7 home basic, Visual Studio Express 2012.

note: My code has nothing to do with mouse or any other hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** an exact solution, for to phrase it as an exact solution I've got to figure out the main reason at first; but I've overcome the bug by just removing the mouse driver and let Windows to manage the mouse via it's generic driver.